# How to find out when GKE cluster was created?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In google cloud console there is a dashboard page with a list of clusters. How to find out when GKE clusters were created? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this advanced filter in the Cloud Logging to know when the cluster has been created:

```
resource.type="gke_cluster"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission="container.clusters.create"
resource.labels.cluster_name="your-cluster-name"
```

Also using the gcloud command you can get creation time:

```
gcloud container clusters describe YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE
```